# MBProgressHUD cannot cover Keyboard

Tags: ios, mbprogresshud

When I try to show a MBProgressHUD while the keyboard is also showing, I use the code below but the HUD object cannot cover the keyboard:

```
SNSSharerAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:delegate.window animated:YES] retain];
HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
HUD.labelText = @"Posting...";
[HUD show:YES];
```

I thought the HUD object shows in front of the window of delegate, the keyboard shows too, so which added last, which is front. Am I wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just hide the keyboard when the HUD appears?  The user will have a hard time interacting with the keyboard with a HUD covering it.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy Because in this case, I want to not hide the keyboard.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add hud to the second window which contains the keyboard.
When keyboard showing, there are two UIWindow instances in application. The first one is the regular window, the second one is the temp keyboard window.
Code:

```
UIWindow *tempKeyboardWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
MBProgressHUD *hud=[[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:tempKeyboardWindow];
hub.mode=MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
hub.labelText=@"Sending...";
[tempKeyboardWindow addSubview:hud];
[hud show:YES];
```

Tested in ios4.3 and ios5.x, it really works.

Comment: +1, works on iOS7 too! To simplify the code just replace hud init method with this one: MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:tempKeyboardWindow animated:YES]; then you can delete the last two lines of code ([tempKeyboardWindow addSubview:hud]; and
[hud show:YES];)

Comment: application Crash for your Code. I am worked on ios12.2

Answer (score 2):

for ios 9 instead [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1] try use [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject]

so it will be like this

```
UIWindow *tempKeyboardWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject];
MBProgressHUD *hud=[[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:tempKeyboardWindow];
hub.mode=MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
hub.labelText=@"Sending...";
[tempKeyboardWindow addSubview:hud];
[hud show:YES];
```